Is this a bug in forallpeople library or am I doing the arithmetic in a wrong way when using handcalcs library?
I am performing hand calculations using handcalcs python library. I have just done the following test calculation using unit-aware calculation with the help of the forallpeople python library:
import handcalcs.render
import forallpeople as si
si.environment('structural', top_level=True)

And the calculation
%%render
A=(70000000*Pa)
B=(5*Pa)
C=A+B

Here are the results:
A = 70.000 MPa
B = 5.000 Pa
C = 70.000 MPa

Obviously I was expecting the correct answer in Pa, i.e. C = 70000005 Pa. My question is: Is there a way of performing the arithmetic, with the units, and get a correct answer. This is only a test: I am performing some lengthy calculations. Of course, one can perform the arithmetic using only handcalcs and get correct answer, but I want to include also units with forallpeople library.

Did you try to increase the number of decimal places in the printed output?

@Ignatius Reilly: I increased the number of decimal places in the printed output to 6 and that solved the issue. Thank you!

The input from @Ignatius Reilly solved the issue.
